# How to find Area from Double Integrals in Polar Coordinates (need help).

Tags: integration

the question is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg2U7.jpg) (it's a graph, please take a look at it). what I've tried was...

$=\int_{0}^{\phi} \int_{0}^{2a\sin(\theta)} \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta$

$= \int_{0}^{\phi} 2a\sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta$

$ =-2a [\cos(\phi) - \cos(0)]$

$=2a -2a \cos(\phi)$

which is not the answer I have to prove, what I am doing wrong? need help!!

Comment: The [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant) is $\rho\,\mathrm{d}\rho\,\mathrm{d}\theta$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin sorry didn't get it

Comment: The integral should be $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\phi} \int\limits_{0}^{2asin(\theta)}\, r\,\mathrm{d}r\, \mathrm{d}\theta$ (explanation see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_2:_polar-Cartesian_transformation))

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin thanks a lot.

Comment: @some dev Tip: put a backslash before trig functions. $\sin$, $\cos$, etc instead of $sin$, $cos$